# I am making code that uses the Return YouTube Dislike API and it's not working. What to do?

Tags: php, api, youtube

I am making a tool that archives data from APIs. The code below is not working.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://returnyoutubedislikeapi.com/Votes?videoId=' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) . '&ref=coreyx');
$obj = json_decode($json);
if ($obj->deleted == false or $obj->status == 404) {
} else {
echo 'Dislikes: ' . $obj->dislikes . '<br>';
echo 'Likes: ' . $obj->likes . '<br>';
echo 'Date Created: ' . $obj->dateCreated . '<br>';
echo 'Views: ' . $obj->viewCount . '<br>';
}
?>
```

I tried turning on Display Errors on my server. No errors showing up. I tried using a PHP code checker. No errors showing up. What's wrong?

Comment: _"It's not working"_ is not a problem description. It's like me posting a photo of my car and asking why it doesn't start. See [ask]

Comment: @ChippyTech, can you explain this line? - `if ($obj->deleted == false or $obj->status == 404) {`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you wanted to use `$obj->deleted == true` instead of `$obj->deleted == false`. With this change and the video [`zwX0Bd05Yw8`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwX0Bd05Yw8) it displays the video statistics correctly on my side.